# android gps parameter pass to web application

Tags: android, jsf

I have developed androide application which generate some double value.

My question is that I have to pass such value from androide application to any other jsf based web applicatoion .

I am trying following code.

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class TestHttpClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "youremail"));
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", "yourpassword"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", "GOOGLE"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source",
                "Google-cURL-Example"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "ac2dm"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
                String key = line.substring(5);
                // Do something with the key
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

How can i retrive such value from jsf coding.

Answer (score 0):

You should have some web services for getting these values in server and in android use HTTP communication using `HTTPclient` do google for `HttpClient` you will get many example.